# Shell Scripting and Intersystems Cache: Extracting Information?

Tags: scripting, cross-platform, process, intersystems-cache, splunk

I would like to be able to execute a script to draw out the current cache process information.  Has anybody done much scripting with cache?  Is there an easier way to basically log the process information?  The end result of this is I would like to present this information in a way that I could log it into Splunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to solve an easy problem using the hard way. Just use the built-in SNMP provider.

The documentation for Cache 2008.2.6 contains a document [Monitoring Cache Using SNMP](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20082/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCM_snmp).

Comment: Excellent, I think this will help greatly.